# How do I install dotnet framework help files for VS Code

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code to write a dotnet core application. Everything works fine but when intellisense kicks in (or I hover over a system API) I don't get any documentation for those methods. I assume that there is an extension for this? Event the node.js system for VS Code includes documentation.

I must be searching for the wrong terms because I can't even find one discussion about this topic.

UPDATE: July 23, 2020 Thanks omajid. I was actually using some apis from System.IO

While I have the xml docs for many dlls, not that assembly:

```
System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.xml
System.IO.Pipes.dll
System.IO.Pipes.xml
System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll
System.IO.dll
System.Linq.Expressions.dll
System.Linq.Expressions.xml
System.Linq.Parallel.dll
System.Linq.Parallel.xml
System.Linq.Queryable.dll
System.Linq.Queryable.xml
```

I guess I'll try to reinstall dotnet.

Also missing the core dll documentation files:

```
mscorlib.dll
netstandard.dll
```

After an install I still have the problem. I can find System.IO.xml in other directories for other languages like here:

```
.//dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.io/4.1.0/ref/netstandard1.5/fr/System.IO.xml
.//dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.io/4.1.0/ref/netstandard1.5/System.IO.xml
.//dotnet/sdk/NuGetFallbackFolder/system.io/4.1.0/ref/netstandard1.5/es/System.IO.xml
```

UPDATE July 26: I found part of the issue. One of my libs was netstandard2.0, another was netstandard 2.1. The newer project had help. See the issue https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/39927

UPDATE August 19, 2020: The issue was marked as a duplicate of this issue: https://github.com/dotnet/standard/issues/1527

Comment: I see that I"m getting documentation for Newtonsoft a package I installed. But nothing for the framework apis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is looked up the `.xml` files that are included in the .NET Core installation.

For each namespace, there's a `.xml` file as well as a `.dll` file. For exmaple, in my .NET Core installation, these are the files for `System.IO.Pipes`:

```
$ find /usr/lib64/dotnet -iname 'System.IO.Pipes*' | grep 'NETCore.App' | grep -v Access
/usr/lib64/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/3.1.0/ref/netcoreapp3.1/System.IO.Pipes.dll
/usr/lib64/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/3.1.0/ref/netcoreapp3.1/System.IO.Pipes.xml
/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.5/System.IO.Pipes.ni.{742a0de4-c892-41d7-a15d-0ecd8de52518}.map
/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.5/System.IO.Pipes.dll
/usr/lib64/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App/3.1.5/System.IO.Pipes.pdb
```

The targetting pack directory (`packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref`) contains both the reference assembly (`System.IO.Pipes.dll`) and also the XML documentation (`System.IO.Pipes.xml`). It sounds like your distribution of .NET Core is broken if it's missing the XML documentation files.

How did you install .NET Core? Can you re-install it? If the problem still persists, can you share more information about how we can reproduce your environment?

We hit this bug in .NET Core on Fedora Linux a little while ago: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1831310

Comment: thanks for the feedback. This is on a Mac, I almost certainly installed it using the installer from MS. But it's been a while so I don't know. I'll look for these XML files and report back

Comment: I definitely see xml files. Let me double check for the specific assemblies I was using.